# PowerShell - How to activate Windows CAPI2 Eventlog?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to activate the CAPI2 (microsoft/windows/capi2) Eventlog with PowerShell.
How can I activate the CAPI2 Eventlog?

I do not have a solution with PowerShell. But I´m sure there is a solution with PowerShell!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to enable Event logs using Windows PowerShell](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/07/15/pstip-how-to-enable-event-logs-using-windows-powershell/):

> To enable it we create a new [EventLogConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338646.aspx) object and pass it
>   the name of the log we want to configure. We enable it and save the
>   changes.

Modified example from this article:

```powershell
$logName = 'Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational'

$log = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogConfiguration $logName
$log.IsEnabled = $true
$log.SaveChanges()
```

Using native PowerShell cmdlet:

```powershell
$EventLog = Get-WinEvent -ListLog 'Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational'
$EventLog.IsEnabled = $true
$EventLog.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Is there any option without using custom COM/.Net objects?

Comment: @bahrep Yes, see updated answer.